# Summing numbers using MPI_BCAST and MPI_Reduce in MPI

Tags: mpi

I'm reading numbers from a txt file called number.txt into an array num[64]. Process 0 is supposed to read the txt file and broadcast num[] to all the processes. I then have to use the reduce operation to calculate the total of all the partial sums and process 0 should finally print the total. I'm not able to print the final value (in variable "total") using process 0. I used an if-loop at the end but nothing prints. The partial sums print properly and are correct. How can I use process 0 to print total?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int size, rank,i,j,count=0;
    int sum=0,total=0;
    int num[64];
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
    
    if(rank==0)
    {
        
        //Read File:
        FILE *fp;
        fp = fopen("number.txt" , "r");
        if(fp == NULL) 
        {
        perror("Error opening file");
        return(-1);
        }
   
        while (!feof (fp))
            {  
            fscanf (fp, "%d", &i);  
            num[count]=i;
            count+=1;
            }
        fclose (fp);
        
    }

    MPI_Bcast(num, 64, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    
        for(i=(rank*16);i<((rank*16)+16);i++)
        {
            sum+=num[i];
        }
        printf("sum_%d: %d\n",rank,sum);

    MPI_Reduce(&sum,&total,4,MPI_INT,MPI_SUM,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    if(rank==0)
    {
        printf("final total: %d\n",total);
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: probably a memory corruption. in `MPI_Reduce(...)`, the `count` argument (in elements, **not** in bytes)  should be `1`.

Comment: The count was just to read the file and since the partial sums are computed correctly, I think the file was read correctly. Do you mean to say I should initialize count to 1?

Comment: `MPI_Reduce(..., 1, ...)`

Comment: Yes, its working now. Thanks!